# Changing the blend mode in Metal

Tags: objective-c, metal

Does changing the blend function in Metal needs setting a whole new MTLRenderPipelineState?

I assume YES, because the MTLRenderPipelineState is immutable, so I cannot change its descriptor and, for example descriptor's sourceRGBBlendFactor property. But I wanted to confirm, as this sounds a little inefficient to generate large objects to change a single parameter.

**Edit:**
I am thinking about a case, where I am drawing one vertex buffer with series of meshes and multiple call to -drawPrimitives:. Each mesh can use a different blend mode but all use the same vertex and fragment shader. In OpenGL I could switch glBlendFunc() between the draw calls. In Metal I need to set a whole separate MTLRenderPipelineState with several state values.

Comment: This answer might give you more info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414629/409315

Comment: Yes, I saw this answer before but it is about setting a blend mode in general, but not about switching it frequently. By now, I just use two almost identical MTLRenderPipelineState instances to perform the same shading. The only difference between them is the applied blend mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some objects in Metal are designed to be transient and extremely lightweight, while others are more expensive and can last for a long time, perhaps for the lifetime of the app.

Command buffer and command encoder objects are transient and designed for a single use. They are very inexpensive to allocate and deallocate, so their creation methods return autoreleased objects.

`MTLRenderPipelineState` **is not transient**.

> Does changing the blend function in Metal needs setting a whole new
> MTLRenderPipelineState?

Yes, you must create a whole new `MTLRenderPipelineState` object for each blending configuration.